# C# cannot find namespace OleDbConnection even though using System.Data.OleDb is there

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have one project (a web application), in production, where I have the following, which works, and then opened up another Visual Studio project (console application) and copy pasted the same code. The problem with the new project (console application) is that while the computer recognizes my namespace "System.Data.OleDb", VS is graying this out, and hovering over OleDbConnection 
gets the error message

> The type or namespace name "OleDbConnection not found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Since my using directive is there, I'm guessing it's the assembly reference, but when I go to Project --> add reference the only options are Projects, Shared Projects, and Browse, and for each of these three tabs there are 0 options to choose from. How can I add this reference?

My simple code is below

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
public class DataLayer
{
    public DataLayer()
    {
    }
    static OleDbConnection conn;
    // some other code below
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing an assembly reference as the error message implies. Go to your project and right click on References --> Add Reference --> select the OleDb assembly.

Comment: I've tried this, but there appear to be no options to choose from when I open this window. I've also typed in OleDb into the search bar with no results

Comment: If you don't have the data access engine installed. Then try Nuget package ADONetHelper.OleDb by Robert Garrisson

Comment: @Casperonian there is no OleDb assembly, it is all within the System.Data.dll

Comment: There should definitely be an `Assemblies` section alongside `Project`, `Shared Projects` and `Browse`. If you open the project properties, in the `Application` section, what does it say the `Target framework` is?

Comment: @raterus is correct. But by default System.Data should have been referenced, no?

Comment: I'm laying strong odds on the bit you've forgotten to mention is that this new project is a .NET Core application (where the Ole classes aren't supported) rather than a .NET Framework one.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm not sure where to find the Application section, and I tried to View --> Property Pages, but didn't see anything regarding Target Framework. However, I chose a default project of Console App (.NET Framework) which defaults to .NET Framework 4 so I'm pretty sure that is it. I've also looked inside the folder that user1011627 references below and the System.Data.dll file is also in that folder

Comment: @kashmoney - Double click on the "Properties" list item that is under your project in the Solution Explorer....it will open a settings pages with multiple tabs...one of those is "Application"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever as it turns out you're right, I realized I wasn't in .NET Framework but was actually in .NET Core. Switching to .NET Framework made it work

Comment: Is there a way to accept a comment as the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.   Only answers can be accepted.

Answer (score 15):

In Visual Studio

- Navigate to the Tools Tab
- Click NuGet Packet Manager

  - Click Nuget Packet Manager Console
    // A command-line console should pop up at the bottom of
    Visual Studio
  - Insert the following command
  - Install-Package System.Data.OleDb

It should be good after that

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the reference to System.Data, where this would be contained.  Ideally you should ensure it is checked under References, but apparently you tried that.

[image]

You could always just edit the project file and add it manually, e.g.

[image]

Comment: OP has indicated that they have no `Assemblies` section in the `Add Reference` dialog. If that's the case, we need to get to the bottom of that before this advice could help. It would also be unusual since most project templates include a reference to `System.Data` by default anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The project needs a reference to System.Data.dll to be able to resolve.   That dll can be located in the following directory (your use may vary based on framework, but pretty standard structure):   C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2.

You should have an assmeblies section in your "Add Reference" window, but you can add by browsing to the location as well.

[image]

Comment: My project already has a reference to the System.Data.dll file

Comment: If that's the case, take a look at Damien's comment above about the Target Framework of the new application you copied this into.  If the target framework of the app is not the same as the target framework that System.Data is (the one that is referenced), you will end up with this compile error.